# Logback configuration file not loaded

Tags: java, maven, logback

I'm working on a maven project and I use slf4j to perform logging but my problem is my `logback.xml` configuration is not loaded and it won't take effect on my project. My `logback.xml` is placed in `src/main/resources` folder

**Dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${jcloverslf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**logback.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE XML>
<configuration>

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
            by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%-5level] [%logger{36}.%M\(%line\)] - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Application logger -->
    <logger name="com.example">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>


    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**Main class**:

```
public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.trace("hi");
        logger.debug("hi");
        logger.info("hi");
        logger.warn("hi");
        logger.error("hi");
    }
}
```

**Expected**:

> 09:34:27.298 [main] INFO  com.example.entry.Main - hi
>   09:34:27.298 [main] WARN  com.example.entry.Main - hi
>   09:34:27.298 [main] ERROR com.example.entry.Main - hi

**Output**:

> 09:34:27.296 [main] DEBUG com.example.entry.Main - hi
>   09:34:27.298 [main] INFO  com.example.entry.Main - hi
>   09:34:27.298 [main] WARN  com.example.entry.Main - hi
>   09:34:27.298 [main] ERROR com.example.entry.Main - hi

Comment: Could you specify what output do you expect?

Comment: What is package of class Main?

Comment: @VladBochenin

         logger.info("hi");
        logger.warn("hi");
        logger.error("hi");

Comment: @AntonTupy 
com.example.entry.Main

Comment: Is logback.xml included into classpath? How do you run your application?

Comment: it is a simple program, so i run it right click -> run as -> java application
and yes src/main/resources is included into classpath

Comment: >[26-01-2018 09:34:27.296] [INFO ] [com.example.entry.Main.main(24)] - hi  
[26-01-2018 09:34:27.296] [WARN ] [com.example.entry.Main.main(24)] - hi  
[26-01-2018 09:34:27.296] [ERROR ] [com.example.entry.Main.main(24)] - hi

Comment: I fixed this by moving the logback.xml into the correct folder (src/main/resources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by deleting jar files from .m2 directory

Answer (score 4):

It is likely, that logback is also included in one of your dependencies, and the build picks up the logback configuration from the dependency, not the one the you provided.

You can check:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

If you find out, that logback is included multiple times in the result, then exclude it from the dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You xml config file is missing `<configuration>` root element:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" />
...
```

Comment: sir, if you can recheck but there is a root element named <configuration>

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html try to replace

```
    <logger name="com.example">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>
```

to

```
<logger name="com.example" level="INFO"/>
```

Comment: Same output, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the following in your pom.XML

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${jcloverslf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Same output, nothing changes

Comment: What are the versions you are using for `logback.version` and `jcloverslf4j.version`? And I hope you have the Main class is under `com.example` package?

Comment: logback.version : 1.1.2  
jcloverslf4j.version : 1.7.9  
package com.example.entry;

Comment: And I presume you have the Main class is under `com.example` package?

Comment: main class is under  
    com.example.entry package

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath, does it contain `commons-logging` as well as `jcl-over-slf4j`? If it does, exclude `commons-logging` and see if that works. I've had problems with apps when they have both dependencies, they seem to conflict.